# IPython interactive slideshows?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to have interactive widgets in my IPython slide deck as I've seen in other presentations. I know how to create Slide cells and I have been able to export a deck as a standalone reveal.js HTML deck. However, this deck isn't isn't connected to a kernel.  How is it that some people are able to put a live notebook into slideshow mode and use interactive widgets?

Answer (score 16):

[RISE (aka "live-reveal")](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE) (from Damián Avila) allows you to create interactive IPython notebooks. Installation is straightforward: download the repository and run `python setup.py install`, which creates all the required files in your IPython profile.

To launch, just run the notebook as normal:

```
ipython notebook
```

In the notebook toolbar, a new button ("Enter/Exit Live Reveal Slideshow") will be available. Clicking this button will bring you in the slide show mode. Slides/subslides/fragments/.. can be defined by using the "Cell Toobar -> Slideshow" mode (dropdown in the notebook toolbar).

Hope this helps.